# Download part of a youtube video using python?

Tags: python, github, video, youtube, multimedia

I've been trying to be able to download only a part of a youtube video
after many searches I found out that this workaround explains how to do that
but I didn't understand where should I put this code to run

```
ffmpeg $(youtube-dl -g 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnW5EjwtE2U' | sed "s/.*/-ss 10 -i &/") -t 60 -c copy test3.mkv
```

this is the workaround : https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/622#issuecomment-320962680

can somebody explain how it works in details

Answer (score 3):

So, for achieving this purpose:
You can these 2 Python modules

1. PyTube
2. moviepy.editor

First Download the YouTube Video using PyTube

```py
# importing the module 
from pytube import YouTube 
   
PATH = "E:/"
  
# link of the video to be downloaded 
link="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxx"
  
try: 
    yt = YouTube(link) 
except: 
    print("Connection Error")
 
mp4files = yt.filter('mp4') 
 
yt.set_filename('holidays')   
d_video = yt.get(mp4files[-1].extension,mp4files[-1].resolution) 

try: 
    d_video.download(PATH) 
except: 
    print("Error Occurred!") 
print('Video Downloaded Successfully')
```

Then you can use moviepy.editor, to form the subclip

```py
from moviepy.editor import *

video = VideoFileClip("holidays.mp4").subclip(50,60)
video.write_videofile("holidays_edited.mp4",fps=25)
```

---

**And regarding the workaround mentioned in the question, That is a command line implementation, so you have to run that command in Command Prompt or Terminal**